# Access properties of an entity declared in .h file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios4

I'm new to xCode and am trying to work with code I did not write. So sorry if this is a silly question!

After running my code, I create Entities here (Entities is defined by Entities.h):

```
Entities *proxy = [[Entities alloc]initWithUri:@"http://localhost:8080/Resource/example.svc" credential:nil];
DataServiceQuery *qry = [proxy person];
QueryOperationResponse *result = [qry execute];
items = [result getResult];
NSLog(@"items size: %@", items);
```

This works great and prints the following:

[image]

**However, I have NO IDEA how to access the variables in Model_person.**

The relevant code from Entities.h is:

```
/**
* @interface:person
* @Type:EntityType

* @key:person_id* 
*/
@interface Model_person : ODataObject
{

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_id;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.String
* @MaxLength:255
* @FixedLength:
*/
NSString *m_person_role;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.String
* @MaxLength:255
* @FixedLength:
*/
NSString *m_person_firstname;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_department;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_contractor;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_supervisor;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_admin;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_workweek;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.String
* @MaxLength:255
* @FixedLength:
*/
NSString *m_person_employee_id;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_billrate;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.String
* @MaxLength:255
* @FixedLength:
*/
NSString *m_person_lastname;

/**
* @Type:EntityProperty
* @EdmType:Edm.Int32
*/
NSNumber *m_person_active;

}


@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_id , setter=setperson_id : )NSNumber   *m_person_id;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_role , setter=setperson_role : ) NSString *m_person_role;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_firstname , setter=setperson_firstname : ) NSString *m_person_firstname;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_department , setter=setperson_department : )NSNumber *m_person_department;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_contractor , setter=setperson_contractor : )NSNumber *m_person_contractor;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_supervisor , setter=setperson_supervisor : )NSNumber *m_person_supervisor;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_admin , setter=setperson_admin : )NSNumber *m_person_admin;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_workweek , setter=setperson_workweek : )NSNumber *m_person_workweek;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_employee_id , setter=setperson_employee_id : ) NSString *m_person_employee_id;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_billrate , setter=setperson_billrate : )NSNumber *m_person_billrate;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_lastname , setter=setperson_lastname : ) NSString *m_person_lastname;
@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson_active , setter=setperson_active : )NSNumber *m_person_active;

+ (id) Createperson;
- (id) init;
- (id) initWithUri:(NSString*)anUri;
@end
```

Note:
I tried to access elements in cellForRowAtIndexPath the follow way:

```
Entities *event = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [[[event getperson] objectAtIndex: 0] getName];
```

and it threw an error saying "No visible @interface for 'DataServiceQuery' declares the selector 'ObjectAtIndex'"

UPDATE:

getperson is also defined in Entities.h:

```
/**
* Container interface Entities, Namespace: Model
*/
@interface Entities : ObjectContext
{
 NSString *m_OData_etag;

    DataServiceQuery *m_member;

    DataServiceQuery *m_cumulative;

    DataServiceQuery *m_date;

    DataServiceQuery *m_holiday;

    DataServiceQuery *m_associations;

    DataServiceQuery *m_department;

    DataServiceQuery *m_person;

    DataServiceQuery *m_project;

}

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getEtag , setter=setEtag : )NSString *m_OData_etag;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getmember , setter=setmember : ) DataServiceQuery *m_member;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getcumulative , setter=setcumulative : ) DataServiceQuery *m_cumulative;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getdate , setter=setdate : ) DataServiceQuery *m_date;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getholiday , setter=setholiday : ) DataServiceQuery *m_holiday;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getassociations , setter=setassociations : ) DataServiceQuery *m_associations;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getdepartment , setter=setdepartment : ) DataServiceQuery *m_department;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getperson , setter=setperson : ) DataServiceQuery *m_person;

@property ( nonatomic , retain , getter=getproject , setter=setproject : ) DataServiceQuery *m_project;

- (id) init;
- (id) initWithUri:(NSString*)anUri credential:(id)acredential;
- (id) member;
- (id) cumulative;
- (id) date;
- (id) holiday;
- (id) associations;
- (id) department;
- (id) person;
- (id) project;
- (void) addTomember:(id)anObject;
- (void) addTocumulative:(id)anObject;
- (void) addTodate:(id)anObject;
- (void) addToholiday:(id)anObject;
- (void) addToassociations:(id)anObject;
- (void) addTodepartment:(id)anObject;
- (void) addToperson:(id)anObject;
- (void) addToproject:(id)anObject;

@end
```

Comment: So `items` doesn't seem to be an array. Where are these 2 pieces of code?

Comment: items is NSMutableArray. What are which "2 pieces of code"?

Comment: Ok, so where is `getperson` defined and what does it return?

Comment: @Wain I updated the question getperson returns a DataServiceQuery (which is another .h file I have included here (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Tb0edV_OwPtJAjjMwvKxhR8UIWlI0gcM73pChIbx5Vs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write somthing like this:

```
Model_person* modelPerson = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = modelPerson.getperson_firstname;
```

instead of

```
Entities *event = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [[[event getperson] objectAtIndex: 0] getName];
```